# Change one pixel of an image file in PHP

Tags: php, image

How can I change the RGB values of one pixel in an image file in PHP? Or is there a better way I should be doing this, e.g. storing an array of RGB values in a database or something?

In case it'll help answer the question, the specific thing I'm trying to do here is recreate r/place

Comment: For PHP, use imagesetpixel which you can set the color of a pixel at the specified x and y coordinates - see the [official_documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php)

Comment: How do I get the GdImage parameter from a file, and then write it back to the same file?

Comment: It depends, if you are talking about a jpeg file, then you may use something like imagecreatefromjpeg. Please study the GD library if you want further information - [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)